# how do I write the formula `Ao = Bo * (1 - ((Bi / (Bi + Ai)) ** (Wi / Wo)))` with the math/big library in Go

Tags: go, math

I have been trying to write a very precise implementation of the formula 'Ao = Bo * (1 - ((Bi / (Bi + Ai)) ** (Wi / Wo)))' in Go using the big.Float type from the math/big library (Bo, Bi, Wi and Wo are very large numbers)

My current approach results in a loss of precision because I convert to float64

```
Ao := new(big.Float)

WiDivW0 := new(big.Float).Quo(Wi, Wo)
temp0 := new(big.Float)
temp0.Add(Bi, Ai)
temp0.Quo(Bi, temp0)

temp0F64, _ := temp0.Float64()
WiDivW0F64, _ := WiDivW0.Float64()
temp0Pow := math.Pow(temp0F64, WiDivW0F64)
temp0Pow = 1 - temp0Pow
Ao.Mul(Bo, big.NewFloat(temp0Pow))
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: You know there are API docs, right? All math operations are _functions_, like [Add](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Float.Add) and [Mul](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Float.Mul)

Comment: There is no `Pow()` function for `big.Float`. You can find an implementation by Rob Pike [here](https://github.com/robpike/ivy/blob/f7e4c14f094b7cee09997d1436a336de4bda736f/value/power.go#L48).

Comment: Yes I know, I just need to know if there's a better way to raise ((Bi / (Bi + Ai)) to the power of Wi/Wo without having to convert to float64

Comment: See the link I posted above. `floatPower()` calculates the power without converting to `float64`. You have to adopt that function.